# Constructing Toeplitz Matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

How can I construct this matrix?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `ToeplitzMatrix`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tm[r_Integer, n_Integer] := ToeplitzMatrix @
  PadRight[(-1)^Reverse[Range[r + 1]- Boole[EvenQ @ r]] 
   Binomial[2 r, Reverse @ Range[0, r]], n + 1]
```

***Examples:***

```
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ tm[2,5]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 6 & -4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -4 & 6 & -4 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & -4 & 6 & -4 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -4 & 6 & -4 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -4 & 6 & -4 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -4 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

```
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ tm[3, 7]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 20 & -15 & 6 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -15 & 20 & -15 & 6 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 6 & -15 & 20 & -15 & 6 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 6 & -15 & 20 & -15 & 6 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 6 & -15 & 20 & -15 & 6 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 6 & -15 & 20 & -15 & 6 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 6 & -15 & 20 & -15 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 6 & -15 & 20 \\
\end{array}
\right)$